# Google Maps Android v1 API deprecated, obtaining API key for publishing

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, api-key

I have developed an application which uses mapView. I have used Google maps for android v1. I finished my app and now ready to publish but unfortunately Google stopped providing API key from March 18th 2013. Now i'm in a huge trouble.

So is there any way that i can obtain a API key for Google maps for android v1, 
or

Can i use  Google maps for android v2 key with out changing my code (Like ItemizedOverlays, Overlays, and Drawings on map)

Please Help !!! 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This the time you can migrate from current Version V1 to V2. Detailed explanation for Version V2 is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro).

Follow steps by steps instruction from the tutorial.

Comment: I have to put up great effort to migrate code from V1 to V2 with the size of the app.So is there an alternative way?

Comment: @user2309642 no other way.want to replace it.Google made a big mistake.Can give an optional.It brings special features in v2. so it's better switch over to that.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can try to address Google and ask them to provide you with a key, although I doubt they will agree doing that.

**2.** No you can't use most of the object you used in the Google Map API v1. Overlays are not supported in V2 and you should use polygones and polylines.